# Swift Spritekit Contact Bitmask and Score Label

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, game-physics, bitmask

I am a fairly new programmer, attempting to make it so that during a bricked breaker like game, when the ball hits the paddle, I would like to add one point to the score. I think I am partway there, but cannot figure it out.

```
    let BallCategory   : UInt32 = 0x1 << 0 // 
    let BottomCategory : UInt32 = 0x1 << 1 //
    let BlockCategory  : UInt32 = 0x1 << 2 //
    let PaddleCategory : UInt32 = 0x1 << 3 //

    bottom.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BottomCategory
    bottom.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = BallCategory
    paddle.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PaddleCategory
    paddle.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = BallCategory
    paddle.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = BallCategory
    ball.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BallCategory
    ball.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = BottomCategory | PaddleCategory
    ball.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PaddleCategory

    var score = 0
            func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
                score = +1
            }

    let label = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Chalkduster")
            label.text = String(score)
            label.fontSize = 50
            label.fontColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
            label.position = CGPoint (x: 568, y: 600)
            addChild(label)
```

These are three sections of my code I believe I need to change in order to have the score work in my game and if you could help me, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to test if the colliding bodies have the correct `bitmasks` before increasing the `score` inside `didBeginContact`. You can use the following code to increase `score` on collision between paddle and ball.

```
func addScore() {
    score += 1
    scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"
}

func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    var body1 : SKPhysicsBody!
    var body2 : SKPhysicsBody!

    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
        body1 = contact.bodyA
        body2 = contact.bodyB
    }
    else  {
        body1 = contact.bodyB
        body2 = contact.bodyA
    }

    if body1.categoryBitMask == BallCategory && body2.categoryBitMask == PaddleCategory {
        addScore()
    }
}
```

Comment: The code now gives the error "cannot referencesa local function with captures from another local function." The error is in the line addScore() in the didBeginContract function. @rakeshbs

Comment: Never mind it took some tinkering but I got it working thanks so much